# Finding Standard Deviation

Tags: python

I am having trouble finding the standard deviation of a list, and not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Code is below any help would be appreciated.

```
n = len(combTimeArray)

numbers = []

mean = sum(combTimeArray)/len(combTimeArray)

numbers.append(int(combTimeArray)

for n in range(len(numbers) - 1) 
        if numbers[n] > mean 
                numbers.append((numbers[n] - average)**2)
        if numbers[n] < mean 
                numbers.append((mean - numbers[n])**2)
        SD = (sum(numbers)/len(numbers))**(1/2.0)
        print SD
```

Comment: Is this a homework? If not, use `numpy.std`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters However it must be noted that the OP accepted the suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3603438

Comment: And what error are you actually getting? please post the traceback

Comment: @KDawG: Ah, interesting. If the OP feels that that edit better reflects the actual code used, then that's always better.

Comment: @KDawG: however, with no actual problem description here (no input or expected output, errors or wrong output is shown), it is still entirely possible that the colons are a major problem the OP was facing. :-P

Comment: output errors are:

 File "test.py", line 73
    numbers.append((numbers[n] - average)**2)

Comment: What part would 
import numpy
SD = numpy.std(combTimeArray)
replace?

Comment: `average` on said line 73 is never defined. I think you mean `mean`

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy
SD = numpy.std(combTimeArray)
```

Comment: what part would

import numpy
SD = numpy.std(combTimeArray)

replace?

Comment: The only thing missing is the assignment of combTimeArray, which is also missing from your question. This code will then put the standard deviation in SD.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to understand your code :p At first you can replace the for loop with a for-each loop -> this makes your code much easier to read and remove the ugly numbers[] statement.

Here is my example code (if you don't want to use numpy or smth. similar)

```
from math import sqrt,pow
numbers = [2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9]

def standardDeviation(l):
   mean = sum(l)/len(l)
   differencelist = []
   for elem in l:
      differencelist.append(pow(elem-mean,2))
return sqrt(sum(differencelist)/len(differencelist))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I had to do standard deviation so you should double-check the math part yourself (and everyone is correct to tell you to do numpy unless you have to do this out for homework or some other reason) but some notes:

1. Python has an [absolute value function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs)
2. You can do a `for n in numbers` rather than accessing each number through an index--much simpler and cleaner.
3. It looks like your `numbers` array first stores all the values, and then you're adding on the difference of each number from the mean to the same list.  Either make a second list or look into the [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function if you want to be extra-fancy.